# MySQL query with two joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have query I need to perform in MySQL on three linked tables. I can do it the lazy way with nested queries but I cannot work out how to do it with a single query.

Tables are:

```
Area:-
 : id     (int)
 : name   (string)

Consultant:-
 :id      (int)
 :active  (1/0)

ConsArea:-
 : areaID        (int)
 : consultantID  (int)
```

I need to loop through all the areas (with `$area` variable) so that I list ALL areas and against each area to indicate the number of 'active' consultants ... so all areas must be listed with a value next to it (which can be zero if there are no active consultants associated)

The first part of the query (irrespective of consultant active or not) I can do with:

```
      SELECT areas.name AS aname, COUNT(consAreas.areaID) AS cct 
        FROM areas LEFT OUTER JOIN consAreas 
          ON consAreas.areaID = areas.id 
       WHERE areas.areaID = $area 
    GROUP BY areas.id 
    ORDER BY areas.name
```

.. but when I want to include the condition of the consultant being active I cannot work out the correct join. It only lists the areas with > 0 active consultants whereas I need all areas.

```
      SELECT areas.name AS aname, COUNT(consAreas.area) AS cct 
        FROM areas LEFT OUTER JOIN consAreas 
          ON consAreas.area = areas.id 
        **JOIN consultants ON consultants.id = consAreas.cons**
       WHERE areas.areaID = $area 
         **AND consultants.active = 1**
    GROUP BY areas.id 
    ORDER BY areas.name
```

Anyone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because of a behaviour of mysql. An inner join following a left join makes that left join an inner join.

```
SELECT areas.name AS aname, COUNT(consultants.id) AS cct 
FROM areas
    LEFT JOIN consAreas ON consAreas.area = areas.id 
    LEFT JOIN consultants ON consultants.id = consAreas.cons AND consultants.active = 1
WHERE 
    areas.areaID = $area 
GROUP BY areas.id 
ORDER BY areas.name
```

Here you can see I'm only using left joins, and more importantly filtering the `consultants.active` status from the left join ON clause directly.

Comment: This gives me all the areas (even the 0's) but it counts all consultants, active or not.

Comment: sorry, i changed the COUNT() directive to use the proper table.

Comment: the consultants table doesn't have an area field - it's a many to many through the consAreas table which has links to the consultant and area table.

Comment: yeah, it would work with any field of the consultant table i guess. Id for example.

Comment: Yes that did it ... I tried the other suggested solutions but they failed in the same way my original one did. The thing is that I would never have thought of using an AND in JOIN statement - I have only ever used them in a WHERE before.  I learnt something!
Thank you!

Comment: if you use a filter in the where part (any filter), the joined table affected by the filtered will be considered as INNER joined. that's the problem: it ruins the left join...

Comment: the JOIN version of this is with a similar but different DB structure:
`SELECT * from color_code
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(cc.id) as id FROM color_code as cc inner join manufacturer as man ON man.id = cc.manufacturer_id inner join manufacturer_bundle as manb on manb.id = man.manufacturer_bundle_id GROUP BY manb.name, cc.code) UCOMBOS on UCOMBOS.id = color_code.id
`

Comment: shouldn't this be in the WHERE? AND consultants.active = 1

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is a `LEFT JOIN` (aka left outer join).

A `JOIN` (really an inner join) selects a row resulting from the JOIN only if it has corresponding rows in both tables.  A left join will select rows if only the left table has a matching row, regardless of whether the right one does.

So in your join to the consultants table:

```
SELECT areas.name AS aname, COUNT(consAreas.area) AS cct 
FROM areas LEFT OUTER JOIN consAreas 
ON consAreas.area = areas.id 
LEFT JOIN consultants ON consultants.id = consAreas.cons
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a `LEFT JOIN` and correct the `GROUP BY`. Try this:

```
SELECT areas.name AS aname, COUNT(consultants.active) AS cct 
    FROM areas 
    LEFT JOIN consAreas 
      ON consAreas.area = areas.id 
    LEFT JOIN consultants 
      ON consultants.id = consAreas.cons
   WHERE areas.areaID = $area 
     AND consultants.active = 1
GROUP BY areas.name
ORDER BY areas.name
```

This will return a table with the name of area and the number of active consultants

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT areas.name AS aname, COUNT(consultants.id) AS cct 
    FROM areas LEFT OUTER JOIN consAreas 
      ON consAreas.areaID = areas.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN consultants ON consAreas.consultantID=consultants.id AND consultants.active = 1
   WHERE areas.areaID = $area 
     GROUP BY areas.id 
ORDER BY areas.name
```